# Docker image of an angular app builds successfully on a local machine but fails to build in azure devops

Tags: node.js, angular, docker, azure-devops

These are the contents of my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "candidate-portal",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "analyze": "webpack-bundle-analyzer dist/CandidatePortal/stats.json",
    "gzipper": "gzipper",
    "compress": "npx gzipper compress ./dist",
    "build-gzip": "gzipper compress ./dist ./dist/gipped",
    "bundle-report": "webpack-bundle-analyzer dist/CandidatePortal/stats.json",
    "postinstall": "ngcc",
    "postbuild": "gulp compress"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^11.0.9",
    "@angular/cdk": "^11.0.3",
    "@angular/common": "^11.0.9",
    "@angular/compiler": "^11.0.9",
    "@angular/core": "^11.0.9",
    "@angular/forms": "^11.0.9",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.16",
    "@angular/localize": "^11.2.0",
    "@angular/material": "^11.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^11.0.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^11.0.9",
    "@angular/router": "^11.0.9",
    "@ctrl/ngx-emoji-mart": "^4.1.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^8.0.2",
    "@ng-idle/core": "^10.0.0-beta.1",
    "@ng-idle/keepalive": "^10.0.0-beta.1",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^13.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^6.0.0",
    "angular-calendar": "^0.26.1",
    "angular-file": "^3.4.0",
    "bootstrap": "4.1.3",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "^3.8.2",
    "crypto-js": "^4.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^2.1.0",
    "date-fns": "^1.29.0",
    "dayjs": "^1.10.3",
    "dayjs-ext": "^2.2.0",
    "feather-icons": "^4.28.0",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "formdata-polyfill": "^3.0.20",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "jquery-datetimepicker": "^2.5.20",
    "jquery-typeahead": "^2.11.1",
    "jquery-ui-dist": "^1.12.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.20",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.32",
    "ng2-file-upload": "1.4.0",
    "ng2-pdf-viewer": "6.3.2",
    "ng2-signalr": "^10.1.0",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^6.2.0",
    "ngx-image-cropper": "^3.3.5",
    "ngx-infinite-scroll": "^10.0.1",
    "npm": "^9.8.0",
    "popper": "^1.0.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "postcss-loader": "^2.1.6",
    "primeng": "^11.1.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.3",
    "signalr": "^2.3.0",
    "source-map-explorer": "^2.5.2",
    "sweetalert2": "^7.26.28",
    "tslib": "^2.1.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.11.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1100.7",
    "@angular/cli": "^11.0.7",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^11.0.9",
    "@angular/language-service": "^11.0.9",
    "@angular/localize": "^11.2.4",
    "@schematics/angular": "^11.0.7",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.2",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.168",
    "@types/node": "~14.14.20",
    "codelyzer": "~6.0.1",
    "gulp": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-gzip": "^1.4.2",
    "gzipper": "^4.3.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~6.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.4",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~9.1.1",
    "tslint": "~6.1.3",
    "typescript": "^4.0.5",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^4.3.0"
  },
  "browser": {
    "crypto": false
  }
}
```

This is my docker file

```
# Stage 1: Build the Angular app
FROM node:14.21.2 AS build

# Set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the package.json and package-lock.json files to the container
COPY package*.json ./

# Check npm version
RUN npm -version

# Change npm version 
RUN npm install -g npm@6.14.17

# Install Angular CLI globally
RUN npm install -g @angular/cli@11.0.7

# Install application dependencies
RUN npm install

# Copy the application code to the container
COPY . .

# Build the Angular app
RUN ng build --configuration production

# Stage 2: Create a lightweight production image
FROM nginx

# Copy the built Angular app from the previous stage to the NGINX directory
COPY --from=build /app/dist/* /usr/share/nginx/html/

# Expose the default NGINX port
EXPOSE 80

# Start the NGINX server
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

and the problem occurs when it's trying to 'RUN ng build --configuration production'

This is execution log while that command executes

> DeprecationWarning: 'createObjectLiteralExpression' has been
> deprecated since v4.0.0. Use the appropriate method on 'ts.factory' or
> the 'factory' supplied by your transformation context instead.
> DeprecationWarning: 'createArrayLiteralExpression' has been deprecated since v4.0.0. Use the appropriate method on 'ts.factory' or
> the 'factory' supplied by your transformation context instead.
> DeprecationWarning: '' has been deprecated since v4.0.0. Use the appropriate method on 'ts.factory' or the 'factory' supplied by your
> transformation context instead.
> DeprecationWarning: 'createBinaryExpression' has been deprecated since v4.0.0. Use the appropriate method on 'ts.factory' or the
> 'factory' supplied by your transformation context instead.
> DeprecationWarning: 'createLiteral' has been deprecated since v4.0.0. Use `factory.createStringLiteral`,
> `factory.createStringLiteralFromNode`, `factory.createNumericLiteral`,
> `factory.createBigIntLiteral`, `factory.createTrue`,
> `factory.createFalse`, or the factory supplied by your transformation
> context instead.
> DeprecationWarning: 'createCallExpression' has been deprecated since v4.0.0. Use the appropriate method on 'ts.factory' or the
> 'factory' supplied by your transformation context instead.
> DeprecationWarning: 'createNewExpression' has been deprecated since v4.0.0. Use the appropriate method on 'ts.factory' or the
> 'factory' supplied by your transformation context instead.
> DeprecationWarning: 'createReturnStatement' has been deprecated since v4.0.0. Use the appropriate method on 'ts.factory' or the
> 'factory' supplied by your transformation context instead.
> DeprecationWarning: 'createBlock' has been deprecated since v4.0.0. Use the appropriate method on 'ts.factory' or the 'factory'
> supplied by your transformation context instead.
> DeprecationWarning: 'createParameterDeclaration' has been deprecated since v4.0.0. Use the appropriate method on 'ts.factory' or
> the 'factory' supplied by your transformation context instead.
> DeprecationWarning: 'createFunctionExpression' has been deprecated since v4.0.0. Use the appropriate method on 'ts.factory' or the
> 'factory' supplied by your transformation context instead.
> DeprecationWarning: 'createExpressionStatement' has been deprecated since v4.0.0. Use the appropriate method on 'ts.factory' or
> the 'factory' supplied by your transformation context instead.
> Error: Debug Failure. Unhandled SyntaxKind: Unknown.
> at pipelineEmitWithHintWorker (/app/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:114185:22)
> at pipelineEmitWithHint (/app/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:113716:17)
> at pipelineEmitWithComments (/app/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:117404:13)
> at pipelineEmit (/app/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:113656:13)
> at emit (/app/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:113629:13)
> at emitParameter (/app/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:114422:13)
> at pipelineEmitWithHintWorker (/app/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:113765:32)
> at pipelineEmitWithHint (/app/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:113716:17)
> at pipelineEmitWithComments (/app/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:117404:13)
> at pipelineEmit (/app/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:113656:13)
> An unhandled exception occurred: NGCC failed.
> See "/tmp/ng-hN7qYo/angular-errors.log" for further details.
> The command '/bin/sh -c ng build --configuration production' returned a non-zero code: 127

what could I be doing wrong ?

Comment: It feels like there's a version mismatch between Angular and Typescript, which admittedly is weird coming from a Docker build. There also appears to be a mismatch in your various Angular dependencies. Have you tried removing the global Angular CLI installation? You'll need to create a build script in package.json which you'll call instead of calling `ng build` directly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not with the npm packages after all , rather it was related to path case sensitivity issue in linux, resulting in build failures